# After Reading the data using HashMap how to check if the credentials are of that particular user?

Tags: java, arrays, authentication, hashmap

So I am trying to create a login in which data is in a file and the data has been read through hash map. So how can check if it the email and password of that particular user and give access?

```
 private void readLoginData(String Email, char[] pwd) throws IOException {
    String loginEmail = LoginPanel.getLoginEmail().getText().trim();
    char[] loginPassword = LoginPanel.getLoginPassword().getPassword();

        HashMap<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file + "\\register.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split(": ", 2);
            if (split.length >= 2)
            {
                String key = split[0];
                String value = split[1];
                hash_map.put(key, value);
                hash_map.remove("First Name");
                hash_map.remove("Last Name");
                hash_map.remove("User Type");
            }
        }
    read.close();
}
```

Comment: your code is confusing. I would say you need to separate the part where you read a file and populate a map from the part you received a user and passwd and verify if that pre-populated map contains a key that matches the user and for this entry the value matches the pass (that's the part you are asking for)

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException yeah sure thank you for the feedback. I will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the read.close(), you can check if the hashmap value for the email key matches the password:

```
String loginPasswordAsString = String.valueOf(loginPassword); // convert the loginPassword from char[] to String  
boolean match = false;  
if (hash_map.containsKey(loginEmail)) {  
    String passwordForEmail = hash_map.get(loginEmail); // get the hash_map value that is associated to the key loginEmail -> this should be the password that belongs to the email
    match = loginPasswordAsString.equals(passwordForEmail);  
}
```

Comment: sorry to bother but i am relatively new to java so in the line ```match = String.valueOf(loginPassword).equals(hash_map.get(loginEmail));``` how is it checking the password of that particular email?

Comment: Hi, I changed the code in my answer a bit to make it easier to understand. Hope this helps now.